# Interpret ratio odds in a binomial logistic regression model to demonstrate effects of variables on the model

Tags: r, logistic, interaction, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I built a binomial logistic regression model and I want check the effect of the independent variables on the model.This is the model `step.model <- glm(decision ~., data = train.data,family = "binomial")` I ran `logistic.display(step.model)` to get the ratio odds as I researched and I would like to interpret those numbers to demonstrate the effect of the variables on the model. Can anyone help?? Thank you

````
logistic.display(step.model)

Logistic regression predicting decision : 1 vs 0 
 
                        crude OR(95%CI)   adj. OR(95%CI)    P(Wald's test) P(LR-test)
Exposure (cont. var.)   2.16 (0.81,5.75)  3.22 (1.12,9.29)  0.031          0.027     
                                                                                     
VehAge (cont. var.)     0.96 (0.9,1.03)   0.94 (0.88,1.01)  0.11           0.096     
                                                                                     
BonusMalus (cont. var.) 1.01 (0.99,1.03)  1.02 (1,1.04)     0.052          0.065     
                                                                                     
Log-likelihood = -133.6208
No. of observations = 801
AIC value = 275.2415
```
````

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, adding 1 to an exposure e give 2.16 more times chances to have a decision 1 than for the exposure e.
And this 2.16 factor is given with a confidence interval of (0.81, 5.75) with 95% chance. This mean that 2.16 is not very precise.
Adding one year to an age a, give 0.96 times the chances to have a decision 1 than with the age a, and this 0.96 is given with a confidence interval of (0.9, 1.03).
For the difference between crude and adjusted odds ratio, the fist one don't take in account others variables, but the second one does. So the adjusted odds ratios give the ratio after controlling of other variables.
As far as I know, the Wald test and the LR (LogLikelyhood Ratio) test are supposed to test the significativity of your variables.

About adjusted odd ratio : adding 1 to an exposure e give 3.22 more times chances to have a decision 1 than for the exposure e, everything else being equal (i.e if all ohter variables remain the same).

Comment: That's interesting and thank you. Could you give an example of how to interpret the adjusted odd ratio too? Thank you

Comment: I added it in my answer ..